# Metaspace issue after switching to JDK 8 and Tomcat 8

Tags: garbage-collection, tomcat8, metaspace

I am facing issue with Meta space piling up and its not clearing even during major GC. Below are my Tomcat JVM

```
-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m
```

(I am running with AWS instance with 16GB RAM)

I can notice that meta space was keep increasing (change in high-water-mark) dynamically, I felt that its changing since the allocated limit is 1 GB and when major garbage collection happened I was expecting unused classes unloaded. But that dint not happen.

For 15 minutes major major garbage was going on and on, Heap space was looking healthy (it cleaned objects in it) but Meta space never. So we have to restart Tomcat to over come this issue.

1. Should I consider MinFreespaceRatio=60? so that G1GC induce garbage collection?
2. I am planning to run `jmap -clstat` on production instance, what exactly i should look out on that metaspace dump?